# ERROR ITMS-90068: "This bundle is invalid. The value provided for the key MinimumOSVersion '8.3' is not acceptable."

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, ios8.3

I need to solve this Issue:
ERROR ITMS-90068: "This bundle is invalid. The value provided for the key MinimumOSVersion '8.3' is not acceptable."

Because I was uploading my application to appstore and presented this error, my app is in the version 8.3 iOS

ThankU :*

Comment: Changing your deployment target to `8.2` or less than `8.3` will work for you. But if you really want to use `8.3` then I suggest you change the deployment target again to 8.2 then again to 8.3, see if this works

Comment: Here are few links that may help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/2682461/468724  https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6986985

Comment: This happened to me now, with iOS 12.2. Anyone know how long it takes for Apple to accept the latest OS?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is Apple does not allow you to set the MinimumOSVersion to 8.3 yet. (I guess because its so fresh ;) )

What you can do is to set the deployment target to 8.2 instead, that will work.

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 1):

If you use Cocoapods you should check value `IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET`for example:

[image]

You should change values to 8.3 or to 8.0 (as well).